# simplexml and accessing feedburner's :

Tags: php, simplexml, xml-namespaces

I'm trying trying to use simplexml to read a feedburner xml. I can read every properties in the xml but not the keys with ':' in it. Example "feedburner:origLink". When I vardump the items, those keys with : doesn't show up. And I can't do like $s->item->feedburner:origLink.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[php]+simplexml+namespace

Answer (score 3):

You're dealing with namespaces, and [this Sitepoint article](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2005/10/20/simplexml-and-namespaces/) looks like a good long explanation. Or for a more concise version, look [here in the PHP `SimpleXML` docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php).

From the docs:

```
<?php
$xml = '<example xmlns:foo="my.foo.urn">
  <foo:a>Apple</foo:a>
  <foo:b>Banana</foo:b>
  <c>Cherry</c>
</example>';

$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

$kids = $sxe->children('foo');
var_dump(count($kids));

$kids = $sxe->children('foo', TRUE);
var_dump(count($kids));

$kids = $sxe->children('my.foo.urn');
var_dump(count($kids));

$kids = $sxe->children('my.foo.urn', TRUE);
var_dump(count($kids));

$kids = $sxe->children();
var_dump(count($kids));
?>
```

Outputs:

```
int(0)
int(2)
int(2)
int(0)
int(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're lazy and don't mind using google webservices, here's an easy way to get the full contents of a feedburner (or other) feed into php:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=100&q=http://feeds.feedburner.com/variety/headlines

You can then just json_decode it and it's all there in your object/array.

Comment: Agree, It is really an easy way to get the full contents of a feedburner. Open a wide flexibility for a customized display.