# How to add some content on header and footer in Google Feedburner message body

Tags: google-feed-api, feedburner

Now before three days, I 'm searching the options for adding the some content in header and footer in our daily feedburner .

So please help me and provide the solution how can I do it.

Needed :

- In the header section, I want to add some holy text and company information.
- List shows in category vise like -- category name then it's 3 posts and next category name and it's 3 posts etc.
- Footer content like add some extra link and company address etc .

So please provide me the solution for this type of the message body in Google feedburner .

You can provide me the link also.

Thanking you.

Comment: Please share the idea or any link also.

Answer (score 0):

I have also been looking the solution for the same case.

So far I just got an idea from *[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33378291/4058484)* to grab the full content of feedburner using Google service like the link as below then display it in a custom way to what we want.

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=100&q=http://feeds.feedburner.com/variety/headlines